# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk' in tkinter Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was making a program that keeps track of covid cases in INDIA. I also got success in the Command Line Version of my program. So, I thought to upgrade it to the GUI version. but I received an error.

Here is the python code:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
print("Retrieving Source....")
site_data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://covidindia.org")
site_html = BeautifulSoup(site_data , 'html.parser')

data = site_html.find_all(style = "text-align: center;")
data2= site_html.find_all("h1")

# GUI Version

updated_as = Label("Updated As:-", data[0].get_text()[1:-1])
Total_Cases = Label(data2[1].get_text())
Active_Cases = Label("Active Cases:", data[2].get_text(), "("+data[3].get_text()+")")
Recov_Cases = Label("Recovered Cases:", data[5].get_text(), "("+data[6].get_text()+")")
Deaths = Label("Deaths:", data[8].get_text(), "("+data[9].get_text()+")")
Tests_Done = Label("Tests Done:", data[11].get_text(), "("+data[12].get_text()+")")

# Command Line Version

# print("Updated As:-", data[0].get_text()[1:-1])
# print(".................................................")
# print(data2[1].get_text())
# print("Active Cases:", data[2].get_text(), "("+data[3].get_text()+")")
# print("Recovered Cases:", data[5].get_text(), "("+data[6].get_text()+")")
# print("Deaths:", data[8].get_text(), "("+data[9].get_text()+")")
# print("Tests Done:", data[11].get_text(), "("+data[12].get_text()+")")
# input("Press Enter to Exit!")
```

Here is Error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Files\python\CovidTracker\main.py", line 15, in <module>
  updated_as = Label("Updated As:-", data[0].get_text()[1:-1])
File "B:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3143, in __init__
  Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
File "B:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-3 
2\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2561, in __init__
  BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
File "B:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2530, in _setup
  self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Comment: Alternatively, there is a library that can fetch covid case for you, take a look at that. `pip install covid`. Read docs [here](https://pypi.org/project/covid/)

Comment: I have updated the question now

Comment: Have you done any research? There are several questions on this site with nearly exactly the same error. Are you aware that the first argument when creating a widget needs to be the parent widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
updated_as = Label(root, text=("Updated As:-", data[0].get_text()[1:-1]))
updated_as.pack()
```

Im just using keyword argument `text` or `tkinter` confuses `parent` positional argument as `"Updated As:-", data[0].get_text()[1:-1]` which is a `str` and hence gives the error. Also make sure to use `pack()`(or any other layout managers) to put the widget on the screen. The first positional argument that widget take is `master` which is the window(`root` in your case), and `text` comes as a keyword argument. You also forgot `root.mainloop()` without which the window won't show up.

Make sure to do the same for all the widgets.

The entire working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

print("Retrieving Source....")
site_data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://covidindia.org")
site_html = BeautifulSoup(site_data , 'html.parser')

data = site_html.find_all(style = "text-align: center;")
data2= site_html.find_all("h1")

# GUI Version
updated_as = Label(root,text=("Updated As:-", data[0].get_text()[1:-1]))
updated_as.pack()

Total_Cases = Label(root,text=(data2[1].get_text()))
Total_Cases.pack()

Active_Cases = Label(root,text=("Active Cases:", data[2].get_text(), "("+data[3].get_text()+")"))
Active_Cases.pack()

Recov_Cases = Label(root,text=("Recovered Cases:", data[5].get_text(), "("+data[6].get_text()+")"))
Recov_Cases.pack()

Deaths = Label(root,text=("Deaths:", data[8].get_text(), "("+data[9].get_text()+")"))
Deaths.pack()

Tests_Done = Label(root,text=("Tests Done:", data[11].get_text(), "("+data[12].get_text()+")"))
Tests_Done.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Also I think it's okay to get rid of `root` since you have just one window, it's fine. But keyword argument `text` is important.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pack() updated_as in the same instruction as assigning it to a variable? Calling the pack() method means it will return None. Maybe try

```
updated_as = Label(args)
updated_as.pack()
```

Comment: It is Not Working